# Replacing chars in word always gives me c as result

Tags: php

I'm trying to "translate" words into a fictional language. For that purpose I've written a PHP-Script which translates the word for me.

The following is what i have:

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="text">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Übersetzen">

</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo translate($_POST['text'])[0];
}

//c  b bb e f h  i j g l  n o p q  t v  w x  y z  ä ö ü  ß
//cr c c  a e cr e e k lc m u c cr k au e cy c kr a u cr cr

function translate($transinfo)
{
    $text = strtolower($transinfo);
    $newtext =
        str_replace('ß', 'cr',
            str_replace('ü', 'cr',
                str_replace('ö', 'u',
                    str_replace('ä', 'a',
                        str_replace('z', 'kr',
                            str_replace('y', 'c',
                                str_replace('x', 'cy',
                                    str_replace('w', 'e',
                                        str_replace('v', 'au',
                                            str_replace('t', 'k',
                                                str_replace('q', 'cr',
                                                    str_replace('p', 'c',
                                                        str_replace('o', 'u',
                                                            str_replace('n', 'm',
                                                                str_replace('l', 'lc',
                                                                    str_replace('g', 'k',
                                                                        str_replace('j', 'e',
                                                                            str_replace('i', 'e',
                                                                                str_replace('h', 'cr',
                                                                                    str_replace('f', 'e',
                                                                                        str_replace('e', 'a',
                                                                                            str_replace('b', 'c',
                                                                                                str_replace('bb', 'c',
                                                                                                    str_replace('c', 'cr',
                                                                                                        $text))))))))))))))))))))))));
    return (translates2($newtext));

}

function translates2($transinfo)
{

    $text = $transinfo;
    return
        str_replace('das', 'das',
            str_replace('emk', 'z',
                str_replace('scl', 'y',
                    str_replace('crcr', 'lc',
                        str_replace('ee', 'z',
                            str_replace('au', 'r',
                                str_replace('eu', 'r',
                                    str_replace('ea', 'cy',
                                        str_replace('cc', 'ec',
                                            str_replace('amk', 'z',
                                                str_replace('ae', 'y',
                                                    str_replace('lclc', 'y',
                                                        str_replace('ss', 'cr',
                                                            $text)))))))))))));


}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

But unfortunately I always get "c" as result.

Anybody having an idea what I've done wrong?

Thanks for all answers in advance!
Filip Zocktan

Comment: Your echo isn't echoing the entire response, only the first character (with the [0] suffix).  Drop that from your code, and see if your results are better.

Comment: Thanks mate, forgot that... At the beginning it was an array that was returned... *facepalm* Forgot to delete that...

Comment: C'mon.... use an array rather than that [ken coding](http://i.imgur.com/BtjZedW.jpg).... using arrays looks neater, is easier to read, and is a lot less overhead than all those function calls

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that?
(Sorry almost complete PHP noob)

Comment: @Mark indenting is cool :-) Filip what Mark says is do like this instead https://3v4l.org/iepWG it's the same as the first three str_replaces you have.

Comment: @MarkBaker couldn't pass up on the first opportunity to technically correct you - that's actually Ryu coding (Ken has a red kimono) 

Comment: The reason you're only getting the first letter (usually `c` in your test cases) is because you're echoing only the first character in the string `echo translate($_POST['text'])[0];` so just remove the `[0]` from the end of that statement. Then you'll see you've got further issues, such as replacing `b` first, then there's no `bb` left to replace. Good luck!

Comment: @JeffPuckett - I stand corrected; perhaps I should refer to it as "StreetFighter Coding" in future

Comment: Another issue you have is using ``strtolower``. This will not convert in your example ``Ü`` to ``ü`` - you will have to use ``mb_strtolower`` instead. Example: https://3v4l.org/f56Zn

Comment: Ok, thanks @everyone!