# Replacing a group of strings doesn't work

Tags: php

I've applied the suggested design with the array for replacing (See: [Replacing chars in word always gives me c as result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099966/replacing-chars-in-word-always-gives-me-c-as-result)).

But now I've got the problem, that the added thing for replacing a bunch of words only replaces 2 Words from the second group.

`

```
function translate($transinfo) {

    $text = mb_strtolower($transinfo);

    $search1 = [[' der ',' die ',' das '],[' ein ',' eine ',' einer ', ' einem ', ' einen '],[' wer ', ' was ', ' wem ', ' wen ', ' wessen ', ' wohin ', ' woher ', ' wo '],[' ich ', ' du ','er ','sie ','es ','wir ','ihr '],[' an ',' bei ',' in ',' in ',' von ',' zu ',' auf ',' durch ',' für ',' hinter ',' über ',' um ',' unter ',' vor ',' am ',' bei ',' im ',' vom ',' zum ']];
    $replace = [          ' %1 ',                            ' %2 ',                                                       ' %3 ',                                                              ' %4 ',                                                                                           ' %5 '];
    $newtext = $text;
    for($i=0; $i<count($search1); $i++){
        $newtext = str_replace($search1[$i], $replace[$i], $newtext);
    return translate1($newtext);}
}

function translate1($transinfo)
{
    $text = $transinfo;
    $search =  ['c', 'bb', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'g', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'ß'];
    $replace = ['cr', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'cr', 'e', 'e', 'k', 'lc', 'm', 'u', 'c', 'cr', 'k', 'au', 'e', 'cy', 'c', 'kr', 'a', 'u', 'cr', 'cr'];
    $newtext = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);


    $newtext = (translates2(translates2(translates2(translates2(translates2(translates2(translates2(translates2(translates2(translates2($newtext)))))))))));
    return translate3($newtext);
}

function translates2($transinfo)
{
    $text = $transinfo;
    $search = ['das', 'emk', 'scl', 'crcr', 'ee', 'au', 'eu', 'ea', 'cc', 'amk', 'ae', 'lclc', 'ss', ' kc', 'crc', 'mm', 'ue', ' dc', 'uu', 'krcd', 'krd', 'rkr', 'rr', 'clc', 'kam ', 'kam.'];
    $replace = ['das', 'z', 'y', 'lc', 'z', 'r', 'r', 'cy', 'ec', 'z', 'y', 'y', 'cr', " k'c", 'z', 'e', 'cr', " d'c", "u'u", 'k', 'c', 'cr', 'lc', 'cr', 't ', 't.'];
    $newtext = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);


    return $newtext;
}

function translate3($transinfo) {
    $text = $transinfo;

    $search =  ['%1',  '%2',  '%3' ,  '%4', '%5'];
    $replace = ["k'c", "c'k", "o'qe", 'qe', "qe'o"];

    $newtext = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);

    return $newtext;
}
```

echo translate("Der Die Das");`

Output is `dar k'c das`
and expected was `k'c k'c k'c`

Anybody have an idea why it isn't working?

Comment: Please create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have uploaded one

Comment: Include the source code in the question and also include the expected and actual output

Comment: Is it okay like this @NineBerry

Answer (score 0):

When the translate() function looks for the words der, die, das, it looks for the words embedded in space characters, but in the input the first word der is not preceded by space and the last word das is not followed by space, so they are not replaced in translate().

This will for example work when using a different input:

```
echo translate(" Der Die Das "); // note the additional space characters
```

Until you explain what this functionality is actually expected to do in detail, we cannot make a definitive proposal on how to approach the task directly.

It seems you want to do the first translation step only on full words. Have a look at [How to split text into words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/790596/101087) for a solution.

Comment: Yeah... Tried here:https://3v4l.org/mETBF (That's what actually is executed in the script)
But of some reason on my Webserver it doesn't work